# Android Build Failure using AS 2020.3.1 with Compose 1.0.0 either InstantiationError or NoClassDefFoundError: WrappedSimpleFunctionDescriptor

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

Upgraded to the new Android Studio 2020.3.1 (Stable) and Compose 1.0.0 (Stable).  When building my branch I get one of two complication failures based upon which Kotlin version I set.

Common build.gradle:

```
    baseDependencies = [
            minSdkVersion     : 26,
            compileSdkVersion : 30,
            buildToolsVersion : "31.0.0"
   ]
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
```

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        gms_version = "4.3.5"
        agp_version = '7.0.0'
        ktlint_version = "10.0.0"
        kotlin_version = "x.x.x"
        detekt_version = "1.16.0"
        versions_version = "0.36.0"
        dagger_version = "2.37"
        crashlytics_gradle_version = "2.5.2"
        sceneform_version = "1.17.1"
        nav_version = "2.3.5"
        compose_version = "1.0.0"
        datastore_version = "1.0.0-beta01"
        protobuf_version = "3.10.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$gms_version"
        classpath "org.jlleitschuh.gradle:ktlint-gradle:$ktlint_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$dagger_version"
        classpath "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:$versions_version"
        classpath "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin:$detekt_version"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:$crashlytics_gradle_version"
        classpath "com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:$sceneform_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        useIR = true
    }
```

Android Studio Current Kotlin plugin version: **203-1.5.21-release-328-AS7717.8**

When Kotlin version is set to **1.5.21**, the following stacktrace is generated:

```
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TypeTranslator
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.AbstractComposeLowering.<init>(AbstractComposeLowering.kt:174)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ClassStabilityTransformer.<init>(ClassStabilityTransformer.kt:61)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$lambda-1(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:146)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$default(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:618)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:211)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:303)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

When Koltin version **1.5.10** is used, this stacktrace is generated:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/ir/descriptors/WrappedSimpleFunctionDescriptor
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.buildFunction(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:842)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.irLiveLiteralGetter(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:933)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitConst(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:426)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitConst(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitConst(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrConstImpl.accept(IrConstImpl.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.transformChildren(IrBody.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.accept(IrBody.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.transform(IrBody.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrField.transformChildren(IrField.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrField.accept(IrField.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.transformChildren(IrClass.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:66)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitClass$s1031542550(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitClass$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:450)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitClass$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor$siblings$1.invoke(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.siblings(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:192)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitClass(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:449)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.transformChildren(IrClass.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:66)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitClass$s1031542550(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitClass$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:450)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitClass$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor$siblings$1.invoke(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.siblings(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:192)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitClass(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:449)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.transformChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitPackageFragment(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:47)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitFile$s1031542550(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitFile$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:496)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitFile$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.root(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:152)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitFile(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:463)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.accept(IrFileImpl.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFile.transform(IrFile.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrModuleFragmentImpl.transformChildren(IrModuleFragmentImpl.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.lower(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:169)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$convertToIr$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$convertToIr$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:116)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:140)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$default(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:592)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:212)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:155)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:303)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.descriptors.WrappedSimpleFunctionDescriptor
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 115 more
```

I also tried going back to Kotlin version **1.4.32** with this result:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: /Users/pc15144/GitRepos/Neal-Android/libs/commonui/library/src/main/java/com/bose/mobile/commonui/ui/compose/CommonCheckboxRow.kt
The root cause java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.inlineclasses.InlineClassAbi.getUnderlyingType(InlineClassAbi.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:239)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:235)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmLower.lower(JvmLower.kt:407)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:147)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:595)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:211)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
```

What magic am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Current Kotlin plugin version: 203-1.5.21-release-328-AS7717.8

Change it to 1.5.10.